# How can I make one div become fixed when another div become fixed?

Tags: jquery, html

I am using **Oxygen theme**, when you scroll down to the bottom, the menu will become fixed.

I want to add something into this menu, so I need to make another div become fixed too, So how can I make one div become fixed when the menu become fixed.

Appreciate.

Comment: Could you please post the jquery/javascript code you are using?

Comment: Need to see more code to really help here, one quickly fix it, one is, if its the class that it becoming fixed then add that class to the div you want to become fixed. If not one way might be to create a class and apply them to both elements you want fixed and then creating some jQuery that will fix the elements at a certain point like you want

Comment: It is a theme, so  too many code. Is there a way like this if this div become fixed, then add this div?

Comment: _“I am using Oxygen theme”_ – theme for _what_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try;

```
var position= $(".FixedElement").css("position");

if (position=="fixed") {
   $(".divClass").css("position", "fixed");
}
```

Here is an example of it work - https://jsfiddle.net/Lzk9vywy/

As you can see it is see that the position is fixed and then fixed the other divs position and moving it to the left.